# POST HTML (E-Mail Template) trough PHP and send formatted Mail not working

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, html-email

My idea is simple the user should have an Option to send mails trough the website.
I use tinyMCE as an editor on my site so the user can design his own style of the mail (HTML Text).

When I hit "Send" the mail that I get is either plain HTML Code or I get weird \n or \r and not an formatted HTML Mail.

**This is my HTML part:**

```
<form method="post">
      <textarea name='body' id='mail' rows='25' cols='100'></textarea>
</form>
```

**This is my PHP part:**

```
 $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

  $mmail->isHTML(true);
  $mmail->addCustomHeader($headers);
  $mmail->AddAddress($address, $address);
  $mmail->Subject = "test";
  $mmail->Body = $body;
  $mmail->Send();
```

I've added the headers that you are supposed to add but it didn't work.

I've tryed with all of these examples to send an nice formated HTML E-mail:

```
$body = stripslashes($_POST['body']);
$body = $_POST['body'];
$body = str_replace("\\r", "", str_replace("\\n", "\n", html_entity_decode($_POST['body'])));
$body = str_replace("\'", "'",$body);
```

but none of these worked for me.

Now my question is how can I send HTML trough my website to send an HTML formatted e-mail?
I'm I missing some extra options to configure on my $mmail or I'm I doing something wrong or is there an setting to tweak on the PHP server itself?

Thank you in advaned.

Comment: What is the value of `$body` ?

Comment: I think `$mmail->addCustomHeader($headers);` is not necessary for phpmailer. Please remove it and retry to see the effect. `$mmail->isHTML(true);` is already sufficient

Comment: @DevWithZachary $body is an html post. Example: <p>test</p> <p style="color: blue;">test2</p>

Comment: @KenLee I've tryed it and it didn't work.

Comment: Make sure you put `$mmail->isHTML(true);` **after** the `$mmail->Body = $body;`

Comment: additional point : no need to use html_entity_decode or str_replace too., phpmailer can handle HTML data if you use isHTML(true)

Comment: @KenLee no it still does not work. But I found out that if I paste my HTML Post raw into my php Code like this `$mmail->Body = "<p style="color: blue;">test2</p>";` then I get the correct formatted E-mail I want, but if I pass the HTML Post trough the Form like this `$mmail->Body = $_POST["body"];` and submit it gets displayed wrong (not formatted HTML). I even took a look in the Google Chrome (Inspect Element) under Network part the Post gets send with as an HTML Text without any single or double quotes.

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with the POST data in your code. To debug, you may echo the $_POST["body"] and see what is happening if you input `<p style="color: blue;">test2</p>` in your form and submit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236434/discussion-between-maybe-and-ken-lee).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was PHP added backslashes \ to the double quotes on the HTML Post.
So I used **str_replace** to remove them.

Then I converted the content with **htmlspecialchars_decode**.

Again I had a new Problem that in my Mail I had "rn" displayed in my content.

I used **str_replace** again to remove those "rn".

This worked fine, now my Mails are being displayed properly as nice styled HTML.

**PHP Code:**

```
$body = str_replace('\\', '', stripslashes($body));
$body = htmlspecialchars_decode($body);
$body = str_replace('rn', '', $body);
```

Thanks for the suggestions @KenLee

Comment: Great to know that you fixed the problem. Have a nice day.